# Deleting Rows from a UITableView That has Multiple Sections

Tags: iphone, ios, uitableview, syntax

I'm developing an iPad Application, in which one of the screens has an embedded tableview with multiple sections.  Each section is populated by its own array (array1, and array2).

I've created a button that puts this table into editting mode.  However, I need to change my

`$tableView:commitEditingStyle:forRowAtIndexPath`

somehow to determine what section the selected row is in, and delete the entry from the associated array as well.  Does anyone have any ideas?

```
-(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView commitEditingStyle:(UITableViewCellEditingStyle)editingStyle forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{
    if(editingStyle == UITableViewCellEditingStyleDelete){     
//This is the line i need to change...
        [array1 removeObjectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
        [myTable deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObject:indexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Looks like you need to remove the row from the correct array... using a switch statement on the sections might work (but only if there's a set number of sections, which you seem to indicate there is)

So where you're removing the object from the array, make sure you're removing it from the correct array based on the section.

```
  switch (indexPath.section) {
    case 0
      [array0 removeObjectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
      break;
    case 1
      [array1 removeObjectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
      break;
  }
```

etc.

Comment: Thanks; all the solutions worked, but the SwitchMethod would be the best way to go about this.

Answer (score 2):

Do like this... Get the required section using

```
 NSInteger section = [indexPath section];
 if (section == 0)
     {
       // write your code for deleting rows in your 1st section
      }

 if (section == 1)
     {
       // write your code for deleting rows in your 2nd section
      }

  // This is the idea...
```

Answer (score 2):

The indexPath variable has the properties row and section. So, you can do:

```
-(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView commitEditingStyle:(UITableViewCellEditingStyle)editingStyle forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{ if(editingStyle == UITableViewCellEditingStyleDelete){

    if (indexPath.section == 1) {
        // do something
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
```

is the method you need to determine which cell you have been selected.

If you just want to determine the actual section which is shown you can do that with `indexPath.section`

```
  NSInteger section = [indexPath section];
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
[[self.mainArrayList objectAtIndex:indexPath.section] removeObjectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
```

Answer (score 0):

The indexPath parameter of the commitEditingStyle:... method [has the section and row](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#DOCUMENTATION/UIKit/Reference/NSIndexPath_UIKitAdditions/Reference/Reference.html) of the cell. Perhaps I'm misunderstanding the question, can you clarify what you mean by 'delete it from the associated array' - do you have one array for each section in your table?